# Eclipse: New Android Test Project does not open the android test wizard

Tags: android, eclipse, testing, junit

This is one of those "I'm going to start doing something new because I should, but the first step is broken" kind of scenarios.  I want to set up testing on my new Android project.  The tutorials I've read all say to go to File -> New -> Project -> Android Test Project, at which point you should see the "Create Android Test Project" wizard with fields such as "Test Project Name" and "Test Target."

I, on the other hand, only get a "New Android Project" wizard with no such test-related fields.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo Release 1 on Mac OSX 10.6 with the Android SDK Level 14.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here, or how to fix it?

Comment: Apparently this is now being tracked and assigned by the Android dev team here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being in contact with the developers of Android development tools assigned to this issue, it ultimately came down to an unclear implementation.  The first screen of creating a new Android Test uses the same screen as the standard "New Project" wizard, and eventually switches to the more Android-specific screens later on.  The documentation and tutorials I was reading were actually outdated, and the usability issue is being tracked with Medium priority at the time of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try

File --> New  --> Others --> Android --> Android Test Project

Comment: The problem isn't that I don't have that option, it's that launching that option gives me the New Android Project wizard, not the New Android Test Project wizard.